# Open test drive in Yii framework in linux.

Tags: linux, yii

I am a bit new to yii so I need you guys help. 
I am trying to create first application in this page.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app

However, I am using Kubuntu and my `www` is under root system `'var'` folder which can't be accessed from terminal service.

```
YiiRoot/framework/yiic webapp WebRoot/testdrive
php YiiRoot/framework/yiic.php webapp testdrive
```

so these two commands won't work. I was wondering if anyone here can help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to navigate to

```
/var/www
```

and then type

```
/{fullpath to framework folder}/yiic webapp testdrive
```

so if you have your framework at /var/www/framework/ your commands should be:

```
cd /var/www/
./framework/yiic webapp testdrive
```

alternatively if you're calling yiic some random folder:

```
YiiRoot/framework/yiic webapp /var/www/testdrive
```

but in the end, you have to be able to call the yiic file from a command line.

If you only have ftp access, I suggest setting up a local server like xampp and installing everything there, and then upload the files to the server.

Finally if all else fails, you can manually create the folder structure and upload it via ftp, though that's a lot of manual work.